# Python Class Initialization Behaviour and Idempotency

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Flask api where I'm trying to construct a class based on the request json body. Its important that the requests are independent from each other.

However, I've found that the requests are not independent of each other.

The first request I make to the api works as expected:
[image]

But an interesting thing happens when I make another request!
[image]

Somehow `bob the builder` is persisting between requests and living in the `allStoreManagers` variable.

Can someone help me figure out *why* this is happening?

[Code Link](https://github.com/timothestes/furniture_store) (its only 3 files, don't worry)

**Python Version: Python 3.8**

**Dependencies: Flask**

**Files:**

api.py

```
from flask import Flask, request

api = Flask(__name__)


@api.route("/create_store", methods=["POST"])
def tbd():
    from furniture_class import FancyFurnitureStore

    kwargs = request.json
    my_store = FancyFurnitureStore(**kwargs)

    return my_store.to_dict()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    api.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

furniture_class.py

```
class FancyFurnitureStore:
    def __init__(
        self,
        storeManager: str,
        allStoreManagers: dict = {},
        version: int = 1,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.version = version
        self.storeManager = storeManager

        # allStoreManagers should initialize to {} every time right??
        self.allStoreManagers = allStoreManagers

        if str(self.version) not in self.allStoreManagers.keys():
            self.allStoreManagers[str(self.version)] = self.storeManager

    def to_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

Final thoughts:

- If I don't put the class in a separate file and keep everything on api.py, the requests are independent from each other. Weird. Why would putting the class in a different file cause problems?
- The allStoreManagers variable is somehow not defaulting to `{}` and instead has the dictionary of the first request in it. Restarting the api clears the variable but it just gets stuck again on the subsequent request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The allStoreManagers variable is somehow not defaulting to {} and instead has the dictionary of the first request in it.

This is intended behaviour of *default* values given to Python parameter variables. This can be confusing when coming from different languages, but in Python those default values are evaluated *once*, at function definition, not at function call.

The way to get a different dictionary instance at each call, is to use `None` as default, and add a line of code:

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        storeManager: str,
        allStoreManagers: None,
        version: int = 1,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        if dict is None:
            dict = {}
        # ...etc
```